# Where to use $E=h \nu$ and $p=h/\lambda$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, momentum, frequency, wavelength

Where to use $E=h \nu$ and $p=h/\lambda$? Because both the methods give different answers. Can somebody explain why is it so?

Comment: can you give an example supporting your question ?

Comment: They should be consistent: E=hv=hc/$\lambda$ <=> h/$\lambda$=E/c=mc=p

Answer (score 3):

When we deal with photons, we have
$$
E = h\nu=\hbar\omega,\\
p = \frac{h}{\lambda}=\frac{2\pi\hbar}{\lambda}=\hbar k,
$$
which are consistents, since the photon dispersion relation is $$\omega=ck\Leftrightarrow E=pc$$.

The relations $E=\hbar\omega$ and $p=\hbar k$ are applicable to other particles, provided that we use the correct dispersion relation, e.g.,
$$E=\frac{p^2}{m}$$ for non-relativistic electrons or
$$E^2=p^2c^2+m^2c^4$$ for the relativistic ones.